# Как унаследоваться от Date? (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Вот вроде-бы логичный вариант:

```
class MyDate extends Date {
    constructor(dateTimeStr: string) {
        super(dateTimeStr);
        console.log(this, typeof(this));
        this.setTime(this.getTime() + 1000);
    }        
}
```

Но оказывается, что, по всей видимости, от того, что `super` вызывает `Date` как функцию `Date()`, а не как класс `new Date`, то `Date` возвращает строку. Соответственно и `this` становится строкой.

Подскажите как нормально можно расширить Date.

Comment: в коде `if` пропущен?

Comment: Не знаю, что за строки у вас, но на чистом js this остаётся объектом https://repl.it/Jhei/0

Comment: @Grundy, да. Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Да, в typescript проблема

Comment: собственно, без синтаксиса с классами проблема и в обычном js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведенный пример кода работает, если используется синтаксис ES6. Отличие от typescript в данном случае только в отсутствии типа параметра, передаваемого в конструктор.

Это возможно, так как класс в разделе спецификации о `Date` есть следующие строки:

> The Date constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value of an extends clause of a class definition. Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified Date behaviour must include a super call to the Date constructor to create and initialize the subclass instance with a [[DateValue]] internal slot.

> Конструктор `Date` определен так, что возможно создавать подклассы. Он может использоваться как значение для `extends` в определении класса. Конструкторы подклассов, которые должны наследовать поведение `Date` должны включать вызов `super`, для создания и инициализации **внутреннего слота** `[[DateValue]]`.

Убедиться, что все работает, можно на примере:

```js
class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor(dateTimeStr) {
    super(dateTimeStr);
    console.log(this, typeof(this));
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + 1000);
  }
}

var d = new MyDate("2017-07-26T00:00:00.000Z");

console.log(d.getDate()); // 26
```

---

#### Почему не работает в typescript, и при ручной реализации?

Проблема заключается во внутреннем слоте `[[DateValue]]`, к которому внутри обращаются все функции `Date`.

Поэтому следующий пример будет кидать исключение:

```js
function MyDate(dateTimeStr) {
  Date.call(this, dateTimeStr);
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + 1000);
}

MyDate.prototype = Object.create(Date.prototype);

var d = new MyDate("2017-07-26T00:00:00.000Z");
```

Реализация, которая идет в typescript [несколько сложнее](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyDate%20extends%20Date%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(dateTimeStr%3Astring)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(dateTimeStr)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this%2C%20typeof(this))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setTime(this.getTime()%20%2B%201000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20t%20%3D%20new%20MyDate(%222017-07-25T15%3A43%3A05.108Z%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(t.getDate))

```
function MyDate(dateTimeStr) {
    var _this = _super.call(this, dateTimeStr) || this;
    console.log(_this, typeof (_this));
    _this.setTime(_this.getTime() + 1000);
    return _this;
}
```

В данном случае переписывается `this`, который будет возвращен из конструктора, и вызов `_super.call(this, dateTimeStr)` в данном случае эквивалентен вызову `Date.call(this, dateTimeStr)`, что просто вернет строку.

#### Как решить?

Победить эту проблему может помочь [ключ компиляции `-target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options), если в нем указать ES6 и выше.

В случае ручной реализации, в [похожем вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6075231/2881286) советуют создавать Date и менять ему прототип, например так:

```js
function MyDate(dateTimeStr) {
  var _this = new Date(dateTimeStr);
  _this.setTime(_this.getTime() + 1000);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(_this, MyDate.prototype);
  return _this;
}

MyDate.prototype = Object.create(Date.prototype);
MyDate.prototype.foo = function(){
  return `${this.getFullYear()}-${this.getMonth()+1}`;
}

var d = new MyDate("2017-07-26T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(d.getDate()); // 26
console.log(d instanceof Date); // true
console.log(d instanceof MyDate); // true
console.log(d.foo()); //2017-7
```

Comment: Не знаю кто минусанул, Хороший ответ. В es6 смысла нет, код для браузера. Попробую ручной способ чуть позже. Спасибо.

Comment: @МистерФикс, на самом деле последние версии уже хорошо поддерживают es6

Comment: не знал, спасибо. А как обстоит дело на опере мобайл?

Comment: @МистерФикс, а она еще жива? :)

Comment: да вроде она нормально здравствует.

Comment: @МистерФикс, а, я наверное перепутал с оперой мини