# Расширить EventTarget, без синтаксиса "class"

Tags: javascript

Как я могу записать аналог `class MyClass extends EventTarget{}`, без использования синтаксиса "class"? В спецификации сказано что это только синтаксический сахар, что происходит при его использовании?

Мне интересно узнать что именно происходит при произнесении этого заклинания.
Я пробовал что-то вроде

```
function MyClass(){
    var tmp = new EventTarget;
    //здесь можно задать новые методы, например tmp.hi = _=>{alert("Hi")}
    return tmp;
}
```

Но в этом случае `(new MyClass).constructor.name` выводит "EventTarget".
Это не удобно для отладки.

Comment: Возможно связанные вопросы: [Конструктор ошибок javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490010/186999) и [Как унаследоваться от Date? (typescript)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697947/186999)

Comment: _В спецификации сказано что это только синтаксический сахар_ - желательно ссылку на _спецификацию_, в которой сказано именно это.

Comment: @Grundy ты пришел сюда, что бы спросить об этом через 3 месяца после получения ответа? [Вот ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). "Классы в JavaScript были введены в ECMAScript 2015 и представляют собой синтаксический сахар над существующим в JavaScript механизмом прототипного наследования"

Comment: Это не спецификация.

Comment: @Grundy это документация, на которую ссылаются все. Сомневаюсь что в спецификациях вообще употребляют такие слова как "синтаксический сахар". А для чего ты интересуешься? Хочешь докопаться до чего-то? Повыпендриваться тем, что нашёл неправильное употребление слова в моём вопросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае конструкция

```
class MyTarget extends EventTarget {
    constructor() { 
        super();
        // init MyTarget
    }
    foo() { 
        // ... 
    }
}
```

(*почти*) эквивалентна следующей:

```
function MyTarget() {
    EventTarget.apply(this);
    // init MyTarget
}

MyTarget.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype);
MyTarget.prototype.constructor = MyTarget;
MyTarget.prototype.foo = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Однако так сделать невозможно, т. к. `EventTarget` не допускает вызов через `apply`, только через `new` — так что в данном случае можно только использовать `extends`.

Если хочется узнать подробнее, нужно читать про цепочку прототипов и свойство `Function.prototype` в JS: например, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) или [ООП в прототипном стиле](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes).

**UPD**

Более точный вариант, использующий рефлексию и изменения прототипа (не рекомендуется к production-использованию!):

```
function MyTarget() {
    const self = Reflect.construct(EventTarget, arguments, this.constructor);

    // init self

    return self;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(MyTarget, EventTarget);
MyTarget.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype);
MyTarget.prototype.constructor = MyTarget;
MyTarget.prototype.foo = function() {
    // ...
};
```

**UPD2**

Вариант для старых браузеров, конкретно для IE, не поддерживающего `Reflect.construct` (также исключительно в демонстрационных целях):

```
function MyTarget() {
    var bound = EventTarget.bind(null, arguments);
    var self = new bound();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(self, MyTarget.prototype);

    // init self

    return self;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(MyTarget, EventTarget);
MyTarget.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype);
MyTarget.prototype.constructor = MyTarget;
MyTarget.prototype.foo = function() {
   // ...
};
```

Также для поддержки IE10- можно заменить `Object.setPrototypeOf(o, proto);`, на `o.__proto__ = proto;`.

Однако насколько я могу судить, всё это довольно бессмысленно. `Reflect.construct` поддерживается всеми браузерами кроме IE, а IE, если верить [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) не поддерживает конструктор `EventTarget`. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

**UPD3**

Исправил ошибку в примере с `Reflect.construct` — нужно было возвращать именно объект от `Reflect.construct`, а возвращался (неявно) объект, созданный `new`.

Дополнительно также отмечу, что для ещё большего соответствия поведению `extends` стоит вместо

```
MyTarget.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype);
MyTarget.prototype.constructor = MyTarget;
```

делать так (чтобы свойство `constructor` было неперечисляемым):

```
MyTarget.prototype = Object.create(EventTarget.prototype, {
    constructor: { value: MyTarget, writable: true, configurable: true }
});
```

Comment: Это не правда, потому что [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl)  умеет конвертировать эту конструкцию в более старый код. Правда одна строка превращается в 36, но это работает. Я сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с этим кодом, там очень много мусора для поддержки всего, но не уверен что получится. Кроме того, как вообще такое могло бы быть, если это просто "синтаксический сахар"? Он не несёт новых функций, только упрощает написание

Comment: Да, мне хочется узнать поподробнее, и это всё я уже прочитал и не нашел нужной мне информации. Какой смысл отсылать меня на какую-то общую страницу, если я пришел сюда, к тому же после ответа в стиле "это невозможно, но всё равно прочитай"?

Comment: `babel` использует `Reflect.construct` вместо `EventTarget.apply(this)` что является не очень тривиальной, но корректной техникой, которая действительно позволяет более точно воспроизводить работу `extends`. Если вопрос касался именно реализации в `babel`, его следовало сформулировать точнее, сейчас из него это непонятно. Кроме того, я бы рекомендовал очень осторожно использовать генерируемый им код в реальных проектах, т. к. он также активно полагается на `Object.setPrototypeOf`, который крайне пагубно сказывается на производительность JS-кода.

Comment: @Петр добавил в ответ вариант, который использует тот же набор техник, что генерируемый `babel` код (но при этом не поддерживает старые браузеры).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Неужели это единственный вариант? Нет способов иначе, без синтаксиса "class" реализовать обработку событий с поддержкой стандартных методов и объектов, не реализовывая свою версию диспетчера событий? Может быть я что-то упустил?

Comment: Конечно же я имел в виду обработку событий через объект-посредник. Что бы я мог обращаться к нему и добавлять произвольную логику, как при обычном расширении

Comment: @Петр насколько я знаю, нет. Целых два способа наследования от класса — уже довольно много для большинства языков. :)

Comment: Не для языка, в некоторых версиях которого, недоступно ни одного способа. Я говорю о старых стандартах. Как я понимаю, объект `Reflection` доступен начиная с ES2015. Если это так, то либо мы с вами все же что-то упускаем, либо в старых версиях JS невозможно расширить этот класс, в чём я сомневаюсь. Прошу модераторов не перемещать эти комментарии в чат, что бы любой прочитавший мог вникнуть в историю вопроса и предложить свой вариант решения

Comment: Кстати, в вашем примере с reflection что-то не так. "Illegal invocation" при попытке использования методов EventTarget. Та же ошибка, что и в случае обычного присваивания прототипа

Comment: @Петр добавил ещё один пример, иллюстрирующий как можно достичь нужно результата в старых браузерах. По сути `babel` использует комбинацию моего второго и третьего примеров с рядом обёрток и проверок, чтобы бросать исключения, аналогичные стандартным, в нештатных случаях. Возможно, стоить просто использовать `babel`, если так нужна поддержка старых браузеров. Или просто написать свою реализацию `EventTarget` — скорее всего она будет быстрее, чем игры с динамическим изменением прототипа.

Comment: Вариант в UPD2 работает как надо и не содержит рефлексии, которая занимает процессорное время. Какой в нем недостаток? Я не хочу использовать синтаксис "class" по другой причине, в нем нет модификаторов доступа, а значит невозможно реализовать приватное свойство. А наследовать мне нужно не только этот объект, как я понял, многие нативные объекты не поддерживают вызов через call, но требуют `new`

Comment: Недостаток такой, что `setPrototypeOf` занимает значительно больше процессорного времени чем рефлексия.

Comment: `setPrototypeOf ` есть и в первом варианте. MDN в самом деле предупреждает о том, что это очень медленная операция и для оптимизации - нельзя изменять прототипы объектов, можно только создавать объекты с произвольными прототипами через `Object.create`. Но так же там сказано что синтаксис "class" всего лишь "синтаксический сахар", значит либо в нем используется один из этим способов, либо есть более производительный способ. У вас есть ещё какие-то идеи? Я только знакомлюсь с прототипо-ориентированным наследованием и мне не понятно как быть в таких случаях

Comment: Когда единственный доступный способ наследования осуждается в спецификации. Я не хотел бы писать собственную реализацию каждой фундаментальной фичи (EventTarget, Event), наследование придумано ведь не просто так. Может быть есть какой-то производительный способ? Ещё раз прошу модераторов не переносить обсуждение в чат, это сделает историю обсуждения решения недоступной для сообщества, а этот вопрос итак не гуглится

Comment: Синтаксис `class-extends` не использует `setPrototypeOf `, он внутри себя может напрямую создать объект с нужным прототипом и вызвать `[[Construct]]` у нужных классов; это происходит внутри движка, поэтому он может эффективно это оптимизировать.

Comment: Только что проверил, оба ваших решения работают и без `Object.setPrototypeOf`, объясните причину добавления этой строки. Если вы упростили и переписали пример из babel, то какие ваши предположения? Я не вижу разницы и не понимаю назначения. Если можно использовать второй вариант без `setPrototypeOf`, то это отличное решение и вопрос можно считать решенным. Давайте разберемся

Comment: Суммируя — если нужно наследоваться от встроенных классов без потери производительности и без использования синтаксиса ES6-классов, то в JS действительно нет такой возможности. Все доступные способы их компромиссы мы обсудили выше. Рекомендуемым способом остаётся, пожалуй, `class-extends`, private-модификаторы находятся в разработке и доступны пока только в Chrome. Новые вопросы касательно прототипо-ориентированного наследования лучше, наверно, всё же задавать отдельными вопросами.

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf` на конструкторе нужен для корректной работы статических методов (у `EventTarget` их нет, так что в данном случае его в целом можно убрать — но нужно понимать, что тогда соответствие `extends` будет неполное). На инстансе `Object.setPrototypeOf` нужен для работы методов (`addEventListener()` и прочие) и от него (или от `Reflect` избавиться не получится).

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно понимаете, что это синтаксический сахар, но он призван упростить чтение кода.

На самом деле происходит прототипное наследование

```js
function EventTarget(eventName) {
 this.eventName = eventName;
}

EventTarget.prototype.eventFunc = function() {
    console.log(this.eventName);
};

function MyClass(eventName) {
    EventTarget.call(this, eventName);
}

MyClass.prototype = new EventTarget(null);

MyClass.prototype.anotherFunc = function() {
    this.eventFunc();
};

var m = new MyClass('It is event');
m.anotherFunc();
```

Comment: Как заметили ниже, этот объект можно использовать только через `new`. `call` вызывает ошибку. Есть идеи как можно наследовать такой объект?